# How to get inode from alias file?

Tags: applescript, bash, unix

In [this MacWorld forum thread](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/142842-aliases-vs-symbolic-links/) aliases are described as

> Aliases can reference an object in the file system either by a 
>   persistent ID or by path. Generally they will contain both 
>   pieces of information.

Is there a way to access the persistent ID an alias is pointing to with either AppleScript or bash?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context? Are you looking for an AppleScript solution, is this about OS X aliases or about symbolic/hard links, where is the quoted text coming from and (because there may be other solutions for your problem) what do you intend to do with the persistent ID once you got it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set aliasPath to "Mac OS X:Users:John:Desktop:test.txt alias"

tell application "Finder"
    set myalias to file aliasPath
    set myFile to original item of myalias
end tell

set filePath to myFile as text
set inode to first word of (do shell script "ls -i " & quoted form of (POSIX path of filePath))
```